# Android avoid back button

Tags: android, kotlin

I am redirecting users from `LoginActivity` which loads `login, register` fragments to `MainActivity` but I cannot stop `MainActivity` of falling back to those fragments when pressing back button.

## Code

```
class LoginFragment : Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {

    lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        ...
        Login()
        ....
    }

    private fun Login(email: String, password: String) {
        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context)
        val url = "..."

        val stringReq : StringRequest =
            object : StringRequest(
                Method.POST, url,
                Response.Listener { response ->
                    val intent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
                },
                Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                    Log.d("eee", error.toString())
                }
            )
            }
        queue.add(stringReq)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        navController = Navigation.findNavController(view)
        view.findViewById<Button>(R.id.registerBtn).setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        when(v!!.id) {
            R.id.registerBtn -> {
                navController.navigate(R.id.action_loginFragment_to_registerFragment)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Note** in my request success return I am redirecting user to `MainActivity` and I've added `finish()` but it's red! <s>apparently `finish()` is working on Java only and I'm not sure which function does the same in `kotlin`</s>

**Any idea?**

Comment: `finish() is working on Java only` wrong, you can't finish fragments.

Comment: @a_local_nobody Good to know, thank you. now what do you suggest for my issue?\

Comment: you could have used intent flags,perhaps

Comment: @a_local_nobody please tell me how maybe your way is better than mine because later on I will need back button in `MainActivity` for it's own fragments (not sure my way is the best)

Comment: to be entirely honest, i'm not too sure what you're trying to achieve.. are you trying to only have one activity active at a time ?

Comment: @a_local_nobody `LoingActivity` (include login and register fragments) using it only once to authenticate users and do not want to return to it after user is logged-in (this was my question) **Then** my `MainActivity` has it's own fragments and by my solution I'm afraid if later I lose ability of back button for `MainActivity` fragments.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`finish()` is a method of an Activity and not of fragment. Hence You are seeing finish in red color because it is unresolved for fragments.

But from fragment also You can call the finsih method of Your hosting activity

```
activity?.finish()
```

This will finish the hosting activity.